# Freeze panes for a very wide table in gt

Tags: css, r, gt

I am trying to get a gt table to freeze it's panes (ideally both for the columns and rows). I found this awesome gist here which gets me part of the way there: https://gist.github.com/jthomasmock/e3c7873fc505b8e9461b823b0a6954cc

However when I create a very wide table that pushes beyond the page, I end up with two scroll bars: one for the header and one for the body. Is there any way so that those two divs can share a scroll bar? I have included a reprex which illustrates the issue.

```
library(htmltools)
library(gt)

gt_scroll <- function(data, gt_fun){
  
  # empty table
  head_data <- data[0,]
  
  tab_topp <- head_data %>% 
    gt_fun()
  
  tab_body <- data %>% 
    gt_fun() %>% 
    tab_options(
        column_labels.hidden = TRUE,
        container.height = gt::px(750)
        )
  
  htmltools::div(
    htmltools::tags$div(
      tab_topp %>% as_raw_html(),
      style = htmltools::css(
        `padding-right` = "12px"
      )
    ),
    htmltools::tags$div(
      tab_body,
      style = htmltools::css(
        `overflow-x` = "hidden",
        `overflow-y` = "auto",
        height = "500px"
      )
    )
  ) %>%
    html_print()
}

gt_scroll(
  head(starwars), 
  function(x){
    gt(x) %>%
      cols_width(everything()~ px(50)) %>% 
      tab_options(container.width = px(400))
          
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a simpler approach which has just one scroll bar and easily lets you freeze the first column (if you set it as the stub) and the top row. `gt` has the function `opt_css()` which lets you edit css that the main `gt` styling functions don't handle. Or if it's easier to just do the css directly.

```
gtcars |> 
  gt(id = "one", rowname_col = "model") |> 
  tab_options(
    container.height = "400px",
    container.width = "200px"
  ) |> 
  opt_css(
    css = "
    #one .gt_stub {
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    }
    
    #one .gt_col_heading {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    }

    thead th:first-child {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    }")
```

The top row and first column both remain when scrolling. The first-child part makes the first cell stick for both scrolling directions.

This won't, however, make the borders scroll since they're collapsed. Add in:

```
 #one .gt_table {
 border-collapse: separate;
 border-spacing: 0;
 }
```

to `opt_css()` and you'll see that the borders for the first column work fine now, but the top borders are still not scrolling. It's easy enough to fix this but it depends on what if any borders you want to have scroll. Happy to expand on that if needed.

Comment: Oh this is pretty close and much simpler! Have you figured out any way so that the top row and first column disappear when scrolling? Right now it looks a little rough but only because of that one thing.

Comment: @boshek I don't quite get what you mean. I thought keeping them frozen in place was the point?

Comment: Right but as you scroll horizontally you can still see a column header appear over the  rowname_col because of that whitespace there. Ideally that would disappear before it got to the rowname col.

Comment: Ah okay I get it. I figured that out and added it to the answer.